# dynamic serializer resolving in flask rest plus based on serialized value in another field

Tags: flask, marshalling, flask-restplus

Is there any option for dynamic serialization based on certain field?

assume model like this:

```
class Action(base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    action_type = Column(Enum(SubscriptionActionType, inherit_schema=True), nullable=False)
    parameters = Column(JSONB)
```

based on obj value in `action_type` I would like to use appropriate serializer inside the `fields.Nested`

is there any option without writing custom field? and if I write custom field, then can I access there whole serialized object and not just the serialized field?

Answer (score 1):

using polymorphism should do the trick.

```
class Action(base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    action_type = Column(Enum(SubscriptionActionType, inherit_schema=True), nullable=False)
    parameters = Column(JSONB)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on' : action_type
    }


class ActionOne(Action):

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'action_one'
    }


class ActionTwo(Action):

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'action_two'
    }
```

then using [fields.Polymorph](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#flask_restplus.fields.Polymorph)

```
mapping = {
    ActionOne: action_one_serializer,
    ActionTwo: action_two_serializer,
}

fields = api.model('Action', {
    owner: fields.Polymorph(mapping)
})
```

and providing definitions for serializers using [api.inherit](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshalling.html#polymorphism-with-api-inherit) like this:

```
base_action_serializer = api.model('BaseAction', {
    'id': fields.Integer(readonly=True),
    'action_type': fields.String(discriminator=True)
})

action_one_serializer = api.inherit('ActionOne', parent, {
    'extra_one': fields.String(attribute('parameters.extraOne'))
})

action_two_serializer = api.inherit('ActionTwo', parent, {
    'extra_two': fields.String(attribute('parameters.extraTwo'))
})
```

Comment: Probably best to refer to the relevant unit test: https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/blob/master/tests/test_fields.py#L1084